# How to add custom indicator in trading view Charting library in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

I have trading view charting library i'm working on it but now i want to add custom indicator in it but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the  solution
pass the custom_indicators_getter in the props to trading view default props
like this

```
 custom_indicators_getter: function (PineJS) {
        return Promise.resolve([
          {
            name: "Bar Colorer Demo",
            metainfo: {
              _metainfoVersion: 51,

              id: "BarColoring@tv-basicstudies-1",
              name: "BarColoring",
              description: "Bar Colorer Demo",
              shortDescription: "BarColoring",

              isCustomIndicator: true,
              isTVScript: false,
              isTVScriptStub: false,

              format: {
                type: "price",
                precision: 4,
              },

              defaults: {
                palettes: {
                  palette_0: {
                    // palette colors
                    // change it to the default colors that you prefer,
                    // but note that the user can change them in the Style tab
                    // of indicator properties
                    colors: [{ color: "#FFFF00" }, { color: "#0000FF" }],
                  },
                },
              },
              inputs: [],
              plots: [
                {
                  id: "plot_0",

                  // plot type should be set to 'bar_colorer'
                  type: "bar_colorer",

                  // this is the name of the palette that is defined
                  // in 'palettes' and 'defaults.palettes' sections
                  palette: "palette_0",
                },
              ],
              palettes: {
                palette_0: {
                  colors: [{ name: "Color 0" }, { name: "Color 1" }],

                  // the mapping between the values that
                  // are returned by the script and palette colors
                  valToIndex: {
                    100: 0,
                    200: 1,
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            constructor: function () {
              this.main = function (context, input) {
                this._context = context;
                this._input = input;

                var valueForColor0 = 100;
                var valueForColor1 = 200;

                // perform your calculations here and return one of the constants
                // that is specified as a key in 'valToIndex' mapping
                var result =
                  (Math.random() * 100) % 2 > 1 // we randomly select one of the color values
                    ? valueForColor0
                    : valueForColor1;

                return [result];
              };
            },
          },
        ]);
      },

And after this onChartReady
```

tvWidget.onChartReady(() => {

//Bar Colorer Demo is the name we passed in description
widget.activeChart().createStudy("Bar Colorer Demo", false, true);
})